# Как правильно отсортировать столбец с типом JSON

Tags: mysql, laravel

Есть товары, у товаров есть доп. поля, они хранятся в отдельном столбике в формате JSON

```
Prod
id |       name      | description | category_id | fields
 1 | Название товара | Описание    | 5           | {"7402": 57}//7402 - ид доп. поля / 57 - значение
 2 | Название товара | Описание    | 5           | {"7402": 13, "7403": "12-02", "7404": "Охл"}//7402 - ид доп. поля / 57 - значение
```

Есть таблица с доп. полями, она содержит ид доп. поля и его название

Нужно сделать сортировку по определенному доп. полю, сортировка делается только по полям, которые содержат только цифры

Пробовал сделать таким образом

```
->orderBy('fields->7402', 'asc')
```

Он сортирует, но сортирует не корректно, например у нас есть несколько товаров и у них доп. поле `7402` содержит такие данные:

```
1
2
3
4
21
6
```

То при сортировки `asc`, мы получим такой порядок

```
1
2
21
3
4
```

Либо - `desc`

```
4
3
21
2
1
```

Как отсортировать в верном порядке?

```
1
2
3
4
21
```

Comment: Не знаю как в ларвеле, но вам надо привести результат к числу. на mysql я бы сделал `fields->7402+0`

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, все работает